# Xpath not reachable while trying to automate datetime calender using seleniumwebdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

Im trying to automatically set up the calender to a predefined date. 
Xpath not reachable while trying to automate datetime calender using seleniumwebdriver in python.

Im using the firebug and firepath to get the xpath. they are installed perfectly on the regular firefox window but when i try the code the same addons are not reflected in the python opened firefox browser.

It says the xpath does not exist

driver.get("http://www.wufoo.com/gallery/templates/forms/employment-application/")
passwordElem1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='pick20']").click()

Comment: I'm afraid you won't get this answered without posting your html and the xpath you have tried.

Comment: added. please check.